# ERROR: Package 'dsinternals' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.4'

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup impacket using python2 in virtual env using these steps

```
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket.git
sudo chmod 777 /opt/impacket -R
sudo apt install virtualenv
cd /opt/impacket
sudo virtualenv impacket-venv -p $(which python2)
source impacket-venv/bin/activate
cd /tmp                                                                                                                                               
wget  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -O /tmp/get-pip.py --no-check-certificate
sudo python2 get-pip.py

cd /opt/impacket
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ng cached ldap3-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (432 kB)
Collecting ldapdomaindump>=0.9.0
  Using cached ldapdomaindump-0.9.4-py2-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting flask>=1.0
  Using cached Flask-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting dsinternals
  Using cached dsinternals-1.2.4.tar.gz (174 kB)
ERROR: Package 'dsinternals' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.4'
```

**Steps tried so far**

> pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade 'dsinternals<3.4'

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.                             
Collecting dsinternals<3.4
^[[A  Downloading dsinternals-1.2.4.tar.gz (174 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 174 kB 1.2 MB/s 
ERROR: Package 'dsinternals' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.4'
```

Answer (score 3):

Impacket now require dsinternals, since dsinternals is a library from 2021, we can search a impacket version older than dsinternals and instal it. Remember to do it with python 2

```py
pip install impacket==0.9.22
```

Comment: This worked for me.